# Get an int from a threadId in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I am pretty new to CUDA. I need to use a thread id in a computation but it doesn't work.  rem is always 0. I need the index of the thread to computes indices in arrays so I can't convert them to floats to do the computations.

the kernel is as follows :

```
_global__ void initializationCubes(float* dVer, float* dCub, int gridSize, float* test)
{   
    int index=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    if(index<(gridSize*gridSize*gridSize))
    {

        // conversion index -> i,j,k

        int rem=index;
        int qot=(rem/gridSize);

        int i=rem-(qot*gridSize);

        rem=(rem)/(gridSize);
        qot=(rem/gridSize);

        int j=rem-(qot*gridSize);

        rem=(rem)/(gridSize);
        qot=(rem/gridSize);

        int k=rem-(qot*gridSize);

            for(int x=0;x<7;x++){

             // these first three are used to test
              dCub[index*56+0+x] =index;
              dCub[index*56+7+x] =rem;
              dCub[index*56+14+x]=k;
              dCub[index*56+21+x]=dVer[((i*(gridSize+1)+(j+1))*(gridSize+1)+k)*7+x];
              dCub[index*56+28+x]=dVer[(((i+1)*(gridSize+1)+(j))*(gridSize+1)+k)*7+x];
              dCub[index*56+35+x]=dVer[(((i+1)*(gridSize+1)+(j))*(gridSize+1)+k+1)*7+x];
              dCub[index*56+42+x]=dVer[(((i+1)*(gridSize+1)+(j+1))*(gridSize+1)+k+1)*7+x];
              dCub[index*56+49+x]=dVer[(((i+1)*(gridSize+1)+(j+1))*(gridSize+1)+k)*7+x];

             }

    }   

}


__global__ void initializationVertices(float* dVer, int gridSize){


   int currentVertex=0;

   for(int i=0; i<gridSize+1; i++)
   {
       for(int j=0; j<gridSize+1; j++)
       {
          for(int k=0; k<gridSize+1; k++)
          {

               dVer[currentVertex+0]=((i*2.0f)/(gridSize)-1.0f)*2.0f;
               dVer[currentVertex+1]=((j*2.0f)/(gridSize)-1.0f)*2.0f;
               dVer[currentVertex+2]=((k*2.0f)/(gridSize)-1.0f)*2.0f;

               currentVertex+=7;
          }
       }
 }



extern "C"
void initializationCUDA1( const int verticesAtEndsOfEdges[24], const int eTable[256], int gSize, int numberParticles ) {

 numParticles=numberParticles;

 gridSize=gSize;

 numVertices=(gridSize+1)*(gridSize+1)*(gridSize+1);
 numCubes=(gridSize)*(gridSize)*(gridSize);

 size_t pitchv=7;
 cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dVer, &pitchv, 7 * sizeof(float), (gridSize+1)*(gridSize+1)*(gridSize+1));

 size_t pitchc=7;
 cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dCub, &pitchc, 7 * sizeof(float), (gridSize)*(gridSize)*(gridSize)*8);

 cudaMalloc((void **)&verticesAtEnds, 24*sizeof(int));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&dedgeTable, 256*sizeof(int));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&dtriTable, 256*16*sizeof(int));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&ballPoint, 3*sizeof(float));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&dpositions, 3*numberParticles*sizeof(float));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&dedgeVertices, numCubes*6*12*sizeof(float));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&result, numCubes*18*sizeof(float));

 output=(float*)malloc(numCubes*18*sizeof(float));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&numFaces, 10*sizeof(int));

 cudaMalloc((void **)&test, sizeof(float));




 initializationVertices<<<1,1>>>(dVer, gridSize);

 initializationCubes<<<128,256>>>( dVer, dCub, gridSize, test);

 float* tmp =(float*)malloc(numCubes*56*(sizeof(float)));

 cudaMemcpy(tmp, dCub, numCubes*56*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
 for(int a=0;a<100;a++){
   printf("%f\n",tmp[a]);
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

gridSize is 40 -> the iteration of the threads go from 0 to 64000

and when I print the values outside of my function, rem, i, j and k are all equal to 0.

> size_t pitchv=7;
>          cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dVer, &pitchv, 7 * sizeof(float), (gridSize+1)*(gridSize+1)*(gridSize+1));
>
> size_t pitchc=7;
>   cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dCub, &pitchc, 7 * sizeof(float), (gridSize)*(gridSize)*(gridSize)*8);
>
> initializationCubes<<<1,1>>>( dVer, dCub, gridSize, test);

Comment: If gridSize is size of size of kernel grid you may try using predefined constant gridDim.{x,y,z}. It won't help with problem, but it might increase performance.

Comment: gridSize has nothing to do with the cuda part. It's a parameter of my algorithm

Comment: How do you know that `rem` is always 0? What are the kernel launch parameters and value of `gridSize` when you see the problem?

Comment: But you didn't say what *launch parameters* you are using when you call the kernel. The symptom you have is typical of when a kernel never runs because of illegal arguments or out of bounds memory access.

Comment: U updated it with full code

Comment: How do you print them outside of your kernel (they are not even defined there)? Please show full code including the host code to launch the kernel.

Comment: You are only running your kernel with a single thread! Thus index is only ever 0, and you are only writing out the results computed with index set to 0 from that 1 thread...

Comment: thanks a lot :) That's my first program in CUDA, I am not yet very familiar with it.

Comment: It's also a good idea also to [do error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) on all cuda calls (cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy, kernel calls, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `gridSize` is the size of the grid, as the name suggests, both `rem` and `qot` will always be zero after execution of your code because they get divided by a value larger than themselves.

If you are looking for indices into a three-dimensional grid, that is exactly why `threadIdx` and `blockIdx` have three components. No expensive division is required at all, just use this standard code snippet:

```
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int k = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

if (i < myBlockSize.x && j < myBlockSize.y && k<myBlockSize.z) {
    // your kernel code...
}
```

and launch your kernel with appropriate values for the y and z components of block- and gridsize, as well as a parameter or global variable `myBlockSize` set to the desired grid size (in case it cannot be factored into integer block- and grid dimensions).

Comment: Thanks, but that not what I need. I go through my array in a linear way and I need this to compute indices in another array. I tested my indices computation in c++ and it works perfect. It just need a valid int to begin with

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. What is wrong with the int `index` you already have? Please show full code. 
And by the way you can still do without expensive division - just calculate the linear index from the three components instead of the other way round.

Comment: That's what I was doing but it didn't work. That's my attempt at flattening the initialization of my big array to simplify it.